# How to get XML String back from a javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

Here is my code that works:

```
        Response response = target.queryParam("start", startIndex)
                .queryParam("end", end)
                .request()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .header(authorizationHeaderName, authorizationHeaderValue)
                .get();

        MyClass message = response.readEntity(MyClass.class);
```

I want to also be able to do this:

```
if(loggingTurnedOn == true)
{
   logger.debug(XMLfromResponseMessage);
}
```

But I don't know how to get the raw XML String from the Response.

Comment: readEntity(String.class)

Comment: That does work, but then the line: MyClass message = response.readEntity(MyClass.class); throws an error saying that there is nothing to read.

Comment: Try https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#bufferEntity--

Answer (score 1):

An answer from another question:
You can use Response#bufferEntity(), which will allow you to read the entity stream multiple times.

```
Response response = ...
response.bufferEntity();
String s = response.readEntity(String.class);
MyEntity me = response.readEntity(MyEntity.class);
response.close();
```